# Resize xib in custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that is laid out in an .xib file. The size is 194 x 200 AND auto layout constraints are set:

[image: one]

and this is what the class looks like

```
class DurationDayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var banner: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfHours: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitHrs: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeek: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
```

But in my collection view it looks like this:

[image: two]

The size of the cells are smaller (97 x 100). IS there a way to make the nib to auto-adjust to the size of the collection view cell?

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem, solved with either of those two solutions:

1. in your storyboard, click Collection View, click size inspector, Set "Estimate Size" to "None"

or

2. in your custom cell class, add this method:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

        let preferredLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes
        var adjustedFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
        adjustedFrame.size.height = 180 //change according to your case
        adjustedFrame.size.width = 100 
        preferredLayoutAttributes.frame = adjustedFrame

        return preferredLayoutAttributes
    }
```

Comment: This saved me over 24 hrs of stress and anxiety ...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Click `your xib` on stotyboard and find right side `Simulator Metrics` and change size to -> `Freeform` later click `Show size inspector` select `freeform` and write there your `width` and `height` later build will works !

Thanks

Comment: I don't see `Simulated Metrics`, as you can see in the updated screen shot.